# Trouble Parsing Atom with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, rss, nsxmlparser

I'm having issues parsing an Atom feed, as in nothing shows up on my tableview for this particular feed. Can anyone verify that [this](http://feeds.feedburner.com/paradisebeats) is working?

Should I not be using NSXMLParser?

Here is what I'm looking for, specifically:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *__strong)string{
    //save the characters for the current item

    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle   appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [currentLink   appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [currentDate  appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [currentSummary   appendString:string];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing the `current..` variables?

Comment: Yep everything is initialized and fine. It works with other feeds but not this one. Could I be using the wrong strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to parse [`RSS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) tags in an [`Atom`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) feed. They both have a different structure and use a different set of tags. You will have to adjust your parser to parse based on the feed type.

Comment: Ah okay. Could you give some example code, or do you know a way to look up the Atom feed element names?